# Jenskins Unable To Deploy War File on Another EC2 Instance Using Shell Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline

I've spent countless hours on getting this trivial working but it won't budge. My goal is to deploy a war file complied in Jenkins on MachineA to MachineB using `scp` command. But I'm it keeps on having authentication errors.

If I manually ssh into MachineA and run the following command, it works smoothly:

`scp -i ~/<keypairdemo.pem> <../*.war> ubuntu@<EC2-PRIVATE-IP>:~/apache-tomcat-8.5.39/webapps/`

Now, if I put that exact command in the `shell script` option in Jenkins, it keeps on throwing the following error. I have tried doing `chmod 777 dev/tty`, it didn't do anything. I've been tinkering to the point I can't even do `sudo su` now on my own EC2 instance!

```
[WarFileDemo] $ /bin/sh /tmp/jenkins3925660300944070231.sh
“Starting to copy the build - aPPLY”
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host <EC2-PRIVATE-IP>, user ubuntu, command scp -v -t ~/apache-tomcat-8.5.39/webapps/
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <EC2-PRIVATE-IP> [<EC2-PRIVATE-IP>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/keypairdemo.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/keypairdemo.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <EC2-PRIVATE-IP>:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Ee13H6eEq0VyQlVMUh2zIPyi/3eO5lMhpoALmCOZS/A
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

The only way I'm able to deploy is using the deploy plugin for Tomcat for which I have enter credentials & URL to the tomcat server. But I want to do all this using scripts.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is the standard `.pem` file we get from EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a host key verification error.

> Host key verification failed.

Try adding -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no to your scp command.

Comment: ``` [WarFileDemo] $ /bin/sh /tmp/jenkins9072010892905506011.sh
“Starting to copy the build”
Load key "/var/lib/jenkins/keypairdemo.pem": Permission denied
ubuntu@<PRIVATE_IP>: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection ``` It throws me this. I think I have a serious permission issues in my Ubuntu. My only way out seems to be only to refresh. I can't even do `sudo -i`

Comment: OK. But this fixed the host key verification error correct?  Post the debug now as you did in original question.